# Connect SQL Server database using windows authentication from IIS Hosted Web API service. Login failed for user domainname\computername$

Tags: iis, windows-authentication

I have hosted my WebApi service on IIS (Windows Server 2012). This service connects to SQL Server (different server) using windows authentication.
Here is my settings on IIS
[image]
[image]

identity impersonate="false"

SQL Server : 2012
Service Developed using .Net 2013/4.5

Error Message:
[image]

Connection String: = Server=XXXXXXX;Database=XXX;Integrated Security=true;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient"

Appreciate any help.

Comment: Check app pool' identity which is being used by your application. This identity needs access on database.

Comment: Setup an AD service account to run as your IIS app pool identity.  Then you'll need to setup Kerberos delegation on the IIS app pool identity account in order to access the SQL database machine behind it.